# Search bar in tableview using objective c with parse database

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, uisearchbar

I've been following a tutorial teaching how to make a tableview with a search bar. I got this to work without problems, but now I learned to make the same tableview but instead of local arrays, I've been getting my data from parse as PFObjects.

I then tried to take the search bar and implant it in my new tableview which uses parse. I can't get this to work. Following the tutorial with the search bar they are using simple arrays stored locally..

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to use a search bar in a tableview that gets its data from a parse database?

This is my code that works with my tableview that does NOT use parse.

```
 @implementation RecipeBookViewController {
NSArray *recipes;
NSArray *searchResults;
}

@synthesize tableView = _tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Initialize table data
recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", 
  @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", 
 nil];
 }


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
  (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:  
(NSInteger)section


{
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    return [searchResults count];

} else {
    return [recipes count];

}
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView   
  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
 reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    cell.textLabel.text = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

return cell;
 }

-  (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath
- *)indexPath


{    
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"showRecipeDetail" sender: self];        
}
}

  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {

    RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController =  
    segue.destinationViewController;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
    if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {
        indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView   
  indexPathForSelectedRow];
        destViewController.recipeName = [searchResults 
  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    } else {
        indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        destViewController.recipeName = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
   }

  }

 - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:
(NSString*)scope
 {
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate 
                                predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText];

   searchResults = [recipes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
   }

   #pragma mark - UISearchDisplayController delegate methods


-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller 
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString

   {
     [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString 
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar  
   scopeButtonTitles]
                                  objectAtIndex:  
   [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                 selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

     return YES;
    }
```

And this is my tableview which get its data from my parse database:

```
@implementation RecipeBookViewController {



   }

       - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
    {
     self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
     if (self) {
    // Custom the table

    // The className to query on
    self.parseClassName = @"Recipe";

    // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell 
      style
    self.textKey = @"name";

    // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

    // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
    self.paginationEnabled = NO;

    // The number of objects to show per page
    //self.objectsPerPage = 10;
    }
    return self;
   }


    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
     [super viewDidLoad];

       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(refreshTable:)
                                             name:@"refreshTable"
                                           object:nil];
       }

      - (void)refreshTable:(NSNotification *) notification


   {
   // Reload the recipes
   [self loadObjects];
  }


   - (void)viewDidUnload
  {
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"refreshTable"
   object:nil];
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:  
     (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation



   {
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
      }

    - (PFQuery *)queryForTable
   {
   PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

           // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first 
 to fill the  table
// and then subsequently do a query against the network.
   /*    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
}*/

      //    [query orderByAscending:@"name"];

       return query;
     }




     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    cellForRowAtIndexPath: 
    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object

  {
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView  
    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

     if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
      reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
     }

 // Configure the cell
 PFFile *thumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
 PFImageView *thumbnailImageView = (PFImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
 thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"];
 thumbnailImageView.file = thumbnail;
 [thumbnailImageView loadInBackground];

   UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
  nameLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"name"];

  UILabel *prepTimeLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:102];
  prepTimeLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"prepTime"];

return cell;
  }

   -  (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:  

 (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
```

forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath

```
      {
     // Remove the row from data model
     PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    [self refreshTable:nil];
    }];
    }

    - (void) objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error
      {
    [super objectsDidLoad:error];

    NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
   }

  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController =      
    segue.destinationViewController;

    PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Recipe *recipe = [[Recipe alloc] init];
    recipe.name = [object objectForKey:@"name"];
    recipe.imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
    recipe.prepTime = [object objectForKey:@"prepTime"];
    recipe.ingredients = [object objectForKey:@"ingredients"];
    destViewController.recipe = recipe;

  }
 }
```

Comment: This is currently closable as a request for off-site resource.  Can you edit into one that shows what you've tried and describes the problem you're having?

Comment: I will. Give me a minute!

Comment: from the tableview that uses local arrays stored in the app code, it has the variable: "recipe". 

I'm wondering what variable in my other tableview using parse is corresponding to the variable "recipe" from my tableview using local arrays.